# JAVAFX Tree view with different context menu

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to create context menu for treeitems in a treeview. The thing is I want to display different context menu for each treeItem. How to implement this? 
[image]

Foe example I want to create "Add Employee" for Acc Dept and "Add Supporter" for IT support.

Based on name of the treeitem the context menu needs to be displayed.

Comment: Use a custom Tree Cell and set the context menu on the cell. I have a [blog post](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/) on doing something similar for a `TableView`: see if that helps.

Comment: @James_D cool idea, particularly the merging of menuItems :-) Wouldn't have expected that adding a menuItem to several menus would work. Re-parenting seems to happen on showing, not on adding?

Comment: `MenuItem`s are not `Node`s, so you're not adding the same `Node` to multiple places in the scene graph. They behave a bit like the items in a `ListView` or `TableView` (except there's no menu cell API), you could readily add the same item to multiple `ListView`s.

Comment: @James_D oops ... assumed (nearly) everything being a Node ... Thanks for the info, made my learn-item of the day :-)

Comment: @James_D hmm ... then could we get into trouble with your approach if the graphic property is set on a MenuItem?

Comment: Interesting question. I think it's likely going to be safe as the context menu is actually in its own window, and you can't show multiple context menus simultaneously. But go ahead and experiment with it...

Comment: @James_D done: added a label as graphic to the addMenuItem - appears on table's contextMenu initially, then in row's menu ... but then it's removed table's

Comment: Hmm, OK I need to think about that.

Comment: @James_D (comments are closed on your blog, so couldn't add this where it belongs) meanwhile, I think that the borrowing approach is doomed: even though not nodes, menuItems are not meant to be used for sharing between menus. they have a parentContextMenu property that's set on adding to the items. Accidentally most of the time nothing much happens if that points to the wrong contextMenu (as do the items in the tableContextMenu once they are added to the rowContext), only blows with actual graphics. Unfortunately, too brittle for production use. Thanks anyway for the nice idea :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public TreeModel() {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Create Tab");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);

        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                TreeItem newEmployee = 
                    new TreeItem<>("New Tab");
                        getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);
            }
        });

        contextMenuProperty().bind(
  Bindings.when(Bindings.equal(itemProperty(),"TABS"))
  .then(addMenu)
  .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));



    }
```

This works. @James thanks a lot for your excellent article :)